# Swift UIPopover storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uipopover

I am getting started with Swift right now.
I am rebuilding an old app completely in Swift. It is an iPad-only app.

Right now I can't get UIPopover working.

I am trying to tie a button in a view(1) to another view(2) with segue "Present as Popover".

None of the elements I add to view(2) is shown in the popover in simulator. It is always a blank / white view.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Is this for iOS 8? If so, try using the "popover presentation" action segue.